# Swift: return to tableview after selecting a search result

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uisearchbar

I have successfully implemented a search function. I want to be able to search my list, select an item on the list, then return to the main tableview while the item *remains* selected. How do I do this?

**This is the tableview without any selections or character typed into the searchbar. Items do not have a detail view. Items do have more information that can be retrieved, e.g. url. This data must be retrieved later when a user presses the "mail" button top left.**
[image: This is the tableview populated with a subset of the full list (pulled from a test database)]

**This is the list with search results. The grey highlight of the cell indicates that the cell is selected. How do I now return to the main tableview, whilst keeping the selection? I only see the cancel-button top right, the cross-button in the searchbar top middle, and the "search" button on the lower right part of the keyboard. None bring you back to the main tableview whilst storing the selection.**
[image: This is the page with search results. How do I return to the tableview?]

Based on the suggested answers, I was able to store the row's index path, using the function below:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath       indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let rowToSelect = indexPath
    println(rowToSelect)
    selectedCellTitle = selectedCell?.textLabel?.text ?? ""
    println("The stored cell is called \(selectedCellTitle)")
}
```

However, I haven't succeeded in reselecting the row in the main tableview. My code is below. It looks like the constant "rowToSelect" is not carried over to another function (see the one before last line of code). How do I fix this?

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
        if tableView == self.searchDisplayController!.searchResultsTableView {
            cell.textLabel?.text = filteredPublications[indexPath.row].valueForKey("fullTitle") as? String
            cell.detailTextLabel?.text = filteredPublications[indexPath.row].valueForKey("journal") as? String
        } else {
            cell.textLabel?.text = publications[indexPath.row].valueForKey("fullTitle") as? String
            cell.detailTextLabel?.text = publications[indexPath.row].valueForKey("journal") as? String
            self.tableView.selectRowAtIndexPath(rowToSelect, animated: true, scrollPosition: .Top)
        }
return cell
}
```

Comment: Add a tag to your cell when you put in in the view, store the tag when you select the cell, loop through the subviews of your table view test if the tag is the stored tag, make the correct cell sellected

Comment: In this approach, what button would a user use to go from the list of search results to the full list?

Comment: I’ve edited my reaction, i hope this clarifies something for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UITableView Delegate has a function `tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath`. This function get’s called when a row is selected.
If you listen for this function and save the selected indexPath, you can use `selectRowAtIndexPath` to (re)select it in your main view.

Implement this function to listen for any selections made in your tableView

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    //get back to your filled UITableView
    //Save "indexPath" to a variable
}
```

When you get back to the view controller where you have your UITableView

```
self.tlbView.selectRowAtIndexPath(“above declared variable”, animated: true, scrollPosition: .Top)
```

Comment: Milo, the results are promising! I can store different values for the selected row in search table view (e.g. the text as string, or the indexPath as NSIndexPath). But, I'm not yet able to reselect the row in the main table view. I think this is because I need to carry the "declared variable" over to a new function, and that does not seem to work. Code in the example above. How would you fix this?

Comment: You have supplied very little (non to be exact :P) code so I will need to guess a bit. You can declare a variable outside of any class `var selected = o` than `selected = messageTableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows()?.first as! NSIndexPath` when you get back to your tableview `self.tlbView.selectRowAtIndexPath(selected, animated: true, scrollPosition: .Top)`

Comment: Haha, code is up! Looking at your reply, I had declared rowToSelect as var rowToSelect = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0) outside of functions (but inside the PublicationTableViewController class). However, the new value for rowToSelect once I select a row in search view, does not seem to be carried over. I think I'm misunderstanding how to carry over a variable.

Comment: First of all when you search the tableview it will give the indexpath according to the newly created search tableview index path, not the original tableview indexpath.

Comment: This will not work just as Swayambhu suggested. The index path of the searched row will not be the same as the original index path of the table view.

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to hold the index of the Cell in your tableViewController, you could use `self.tableView.selectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .Top)` as soon as you come back to your tableView. This will keep the cell grey like in your picture even if you scroll the table.

Comment: In this approach, what button would the user use to go from the list of search results to the full list?

Comment: He dont need an extra button if the tableview jumps back to normal state (all entrys) as soon as the search bar is empty. I would use the delegate and then bind `optional func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar,
          textDidChange searchText: String)` see here: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchBarDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UISearchBarDelegate/searchBar:textDidChange: